# Convert C struct to Delphi

Tags: c, delphi, struct, unions

How can I convert this struct to Delphi?

```
typedef struct a_config {
    union {
        struct {
            char mode[10];
            char name[10];
        } dn;

        struct {
            int r;
        } sm;

        struct {
            int r;
        } xo;
    } config;
} a_config_t;
```

Comment: Is this for interop? Do you need binary compatibility?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unions are equal to the `case of` construct in a record. Not all things can be translated 1:1, but this can.

Note that packing is a separate issue. Though again probably not a problem in this case.

```
type
  a_config_t = record
    config : record
      case integer of 
        0:(dn: record 
             mode : array[0..9] of ansichar;    
             name : array[0..9] of ansichar;
           end);
        1: (sm: record
             r: integer;
           end);
        2: (xo: record
             r: integer;
           end);
    end;
  end;

// Delphi has no eq for "struct x" in "struct x {} y" construct, only for the y 
a_config = a_config_t;
```

Answer (score 5):

A C/C++ union is analogous to a Delphi variant record. The literal translation is:

```
type
  dn_t = record
    mode, name: array [0..9] of AnsiChar;
  end;

  sm_t = record
    r: integer;
  end;

  xo_t = record
    r: integer;
  end;

  a_config = record
    case integer of
    0: (dn: dn_t);
    1: (sm: sm_t);
    2: (xo: xo_t);
  end;
```

Read more about variant records in the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records

In this case you could make a much simpler translation by removing the nested records:

```
type
  a_config = record
    case integer of
    0: (mode, name: array [0..9] of AnsiChar);
    1: (r: integer);
  end;
```

Comment: NP, variant records are not that often used. Besides, I think the syntax is not in style with the rest of the language.

Comment: Not in Delphi, but in classic pascal that disallowed hard casts, they were the only binary type conversion possibility. Or was that Modula2?, I always mix them up

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I'm sure Modula-2 allowed type casts and conversions. As I recall, in some ways Modula-2 was a little more lax than the original Pascal. It was intended to be used as a systems programming language. It's been a loooong time since I coded in Modula-2 ..........